# How to fix the problem in my Measure - doesn't iterate correctly and I get wrong totals

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Simply using 2 tables in a relationship with the product ID, trying to find the production costs for the amount we have in stock at any given date. In the table with production data I've created a new column to rank latest batches produced per product ID starting with Rank = 1 is the latest via date, and 2 is the latest after that, and so forth.

So if we have 1000 units of product X in stock, 500 produced in the latest batch with production cost of 10, and 800 produced in the batch before that with production cost of 100, it would take the entire cost of rank 1, and the cost of 500 units in the rank 2 totaling at 10+62,5 giving product X current stock the value of 62,5.

EDIT: uploaded an .xlsx file with some data so you get the idea
https://gofile.io/d/hRtl7Z

Brief overview, wh data and result sheet has both the warehouse data (warehouseid, product id and stock qty) and the ultimate result of the Measure in NewValueForStock.
productiondata sheet has the production data used in calculating NewValueForStock.
TLDR; Measure should iterate through productiondata for each product, calculating costs per batch from rank 1 upwards untill produced qty = stock qty.

wh data and result sheet has correct values on each row, but the problem lies in observing results in power bi, as if I want to see the NewValueForStock for each WarehouseID, the results are dogshit as seen on J4, for WH ID 12 results are correct only because there is only one product id currently.

Now, I had it up and working but it required some manual labour in excel as total rows, or the warehouse number totals didn't make any sense, straight up problem with iteration, now that i'm being fed live warehouse data on daily basis I wanted to fix it, and i'm having hard time doing so.

This is the measure, I've tried changing vars to stand alone measures and all that, but I don't know my head is drawing blank. I know the measure isn't the prettiest and not the most nicest to look at, but hey it (used to) do the job.

```
VAR stock qty = SUMX(warehousedata,warehousedata[amountinstock])

VAR num0qty = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=1),[painosm])
VAR num0unitcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=1),[unitcost])
VAR num0batchcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=1),[batchcost])

VAR num1qty = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=2),[painosm])
VAR num1unitcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=2),[unitcost])
VAR num1batchcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=2),[batchcost])

VAR num2qty = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=3),[painosm])
VAR num2unitcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=3),[unitcost])
VAR num2batchcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=3),[batchcost])

VAR num3qty = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=4),[painosm])
VAR num3unitcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=4),[unitcost])
VAR num3batchcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=4),[batchcost])

VAR num4qty = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=5),[painosm])
VAR num4unitcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=5),[unitcost])
VAR num4batchcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=5),[batchcost])

VAR num5qty = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=6),[painosm])
VAR num5unitcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=6),[unitcost])
VAR num5batchcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=6),[batchcost])

VAR num6qty = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=7),[painosm])
VAR num6unitcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=7),[unitcost])
VAR num6batchcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=7),[batchcost])

VAR num7qty = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=8),[painosm])
VAR num7unitcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=8),[unitcost])
VAR num7batchcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=8),[batchcost])

VAR num8qty = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=9),[painosm])
VAR num8unitcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=9),[unitcost])
VAR num8batchcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=9),[batchcost])

VAR num9qty = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=10),[painosm])
VAR num9unitcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=10),[unitcost])
VAR num9batchcost = SUMX(FILTER(productiondata, productiondata[Rank]=10),[batchcost])

var r1 = if(num0qty < stock qty,num0batchcost,num0unitcost * stock qty)
var r2 = if(num0qty+num1qty < stock qty, num1batchcost,num1unitcost * IF((stock qty - num0qty) >= 0, stock qty - num0qty,0))
var r3 = if(num0qty+num1qty+num2qty < stock qty, num2batchcost,num2unitcost * IF((stock qty - num0qty - num1qty) >= 0, stock qty - num0qty - num1qty,0))
var r4 = if(num0qty+num1qty+num2qty+num3qty < stock qty, num3batchcost,num3unitcost * IF((stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty) >= 0, stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty,0))
var r5 = if(num0qty+num1qty+num2qty+num3qty+num4qty < stock qty, num4batchcost,num4unitcost * IF((stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty) >= 0, stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty,0))
var r6 = if(num0qty+num1qty+num2qty+num3qty+num4qty+num5qty < stock qty, num5batchcost,num5unitcost * IF((stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty - num4qty) >= 0, stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty - num4qty,0))
var r7 = if(num0qty+num1qty+num2qty+num3qty+num4qty+num5qty+num6qty < stock qty, num6batchcost,num6unitcost * IF((stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty - num4qty - num5qty) >= 0, stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty - num4qty - num5qty,0))
var r8 = if(num0qty+num1qty+num2qty+num3qty+num4qty+num5qty+num6qty+num7qty < stock qty, num7batchcost,num7unitcost * IF((stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty - num4qty - num5qty - num6qty) >= 0, stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty - num4qty - num5qty - num6qty,0))
var r9 = if(num0qty+num1qty+num2qty+num3qty+num4qty+num5qty+num6qty+num7qty+num8qty < stock qty, num8batchcost,num8unitcost * IF((stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty - num4qty - num5qty - num6qty - num7qty) >= 0, stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty - num4qty - num5qty - num6qty - num7qty,0))
var r10 = if(num0qty+num1qty+num2qty+num3qty+num4qty+num5qty+num6qty+num7qty+num8qty+num9qty < stock qty, num9batchcost,num9unitcost * IF((stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty - num4qty - num5qty - num6qty - num7qty - num8qty) >= 0, stock qty - num0qty - num1qty - num2qty - num3qty - num4qty - num5qty - num6qty - num7qty - num8qty,0))

return r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9+r10


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr0Bi.png
```

Comment: What is your specific question? Also, this is pretty hard to answer without seeing some example data, your current result, and your desired result.

Comment: Edited original post, added a link to .xlsx file with some data. TLDR;
Measure works on productid level, however when observing totals per warehouseid results are wrong. straight up iteration problem that I haven't been able to crack.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by creating 30 additional columns to the warehouse data table. Used CALCULATE(SUMX( to get the quantity, unitcost and batchcost for each Rank(1-10) from the other table where productiondata lies.

Used the exact same measure as pasted above, switched VARs to point to the columns created, and instead of a Measure i created calculated column to the warehouse data table. Now, all of the calculations are done on the same table on row level and none of the problems with total rows is present.